# How to perform same DML statements on two different servers (Oracle and SQL-Server) simultaneously

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have two servers, Oracle and SQL-Server.

I have same database on both the servers.

I want to perform DML (insert,update,delete).

How can I perform same DML statements on both the servers simultaneously ?

If I insert one statement in SQL-Server then the same statement should be updated in the Oracle database .

Comment: By SQL, do you mean SQL Server?

Comment: yes SQL SERVER .

Comment: are you trying to do this from an application your're writing? or from some kind of client (like SSMS) that support both DBMSs?

Comment: i am trying to do this as a client (SSMS)

Comment: Do you really mean simultaneously?  So every transaction will incur the overhead of a two-phase commit and the system will be unusable if either database is unavailable?  Generally, that's not what you want.  Generally, you want to replicate data from one system to the other asynchronously which brings up the question of what sort of lag you can tolerate and whether the replication needs to be bidirectional.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have enough reputation to write a comment so I am writing here. It may be an unswer to your question.

I have never tried, but it should work. You can add an Oracle database into your SQL Server as a linked server and then write a trigger in the sql server and perform the insert to Oracle via OpenQuery. This should be the easiest way and should work.